# CKEditor 5 custom build using my commercial licence

Tags: angular, ckeditdor5

I am using angular 16 with custom build of CKEditor5. All works well but now I want to use my commercial licence. I am very lost as to where do I put my licence key. If I include it in custom build, I still get the icon below the editor and I still am not able to use the table features. The table button does not appear on my toolbar and the ckeditor Icon still show on the bottom of the editor. Please see the image

[image]